# Deserialize a json object into a library class

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm working on some android code right now and I need to save an object using SharedPreferences and to do so I thought I might use Gson to turn it into a Json string and store the string. The problem is that when I try to deserialize it I get an illegal argument exception caused by fields that don't deserialize properly. I want to write a custom deserialize method for this class but the class is from an API that I have as a library that I do not have access to. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is the text from the logcat corresponding to this issue:

```
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434): Process: com.example.planit, PID: 28434
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid value for field
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at java.lang.reflect.Field.setField(Native Method)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:585)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at com.google.api.client.util.FieldInfo.setFieldValue(FieldInfo.java:245)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at com.google.api.client.util.FieldInfo.setValue(FieldInfo.java:206)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.put(GenericData.java:103)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.put(GenericData.java:47)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:189)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:146)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:755)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:721)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:670)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:642)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at com.example.planit.TabbedActivity.getPlanItID(TabbedActivity.java:34)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at com.example.planit.FriendsSectionFragment.onCreate(FriendsSectionFragment.java:39)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1678)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:859)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-20 14:29:42.600: E/AndroidRuntime(28434):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you really need to store all the data in shared preferences? why don't just you create an API model and store it to sqlite database?

Comment: Try `Gson` library from google `https://sites.google.com/site/gson`

Comment: @nayoso It's not my design decision so I'm just trying it this way

Comment: @Panther that's what I'm trying and it won't deserialize the object properly which is the problem I'm running into

Comment: OK I will try to help you with an answer later

Comment: all are primitive data types ??

Comment: Share the original logcat error please.

Comment: @aegean there's the logcat info

Comment: @IanPanzica, you can serialize an object to json and store it, but you have error on deserializing it again to an object, is that correct? If so I suspect that the mapping to the class does not match with the json value at your gson.fromJson call. If you can share the code you used, the mapping class with its fields and a sample json value, you'll probably get the answer here.

Comment: @aegean yeah that's definitely the issue and I really wish I could but the class itself is in a protected api that I don't really have access to which is the problem

Comment: I guess you are doing something wrong while deserializing the json value to the correct Java class. Sorry but without any code it does not seem to be answered. I can suggest you to write a pojo class which has the same fields with your json value. Use that class while deserializing. After deserialization, you'll have an object which is filled by the json value. If you want, you can create an instance of your protected api's class and map the fields.